# universe U2.net SELECT wildcard

Tags: wildcard, universe

When i use SQL to query MS access or MS SQL. I can have the following sql to retrieve data

```
SELECT ORDER_NO,NAME FROM ORDER WHERE LEFT(ORDER_NO,6)='123456'
```

to retrieve the record with order number start with '123456'

But LEFT is not working in the Universe U2.net.

What is do is below, but the query return result slow.

```
SELECT ORDER_NO,NAME FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER_NO LIKE '%123456%'
```

I am looking for alternative for , LEFT,MID and etc to optimize the code

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

UniverseSQL has very limited string functions and LEFT is not among them.
It has SUBSTRING() using the ANSI syntax.

```
SUBSTRING(string_expression FROM start FOR length)
```

The FOR section is optional and its omission will return the remainder of the string after the start.

Answer (score 0):

Is it any faster if you drop the first '%'? You are looking for a 123456 in any part of the field instead of just starting from the beginning of the field.

This requires the entire value of every that field in every record to be read and evaluated instead of just the first character. With a large set of data this could be a big difference, especially on a non-indexed field.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the selection operators instead.  I think this would be faster, but didn't test:
SELECT ORDER_NO,NAME FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER_NO = "123456]'

For order with the keyword in the middle you would do:
SELECT ORDER_NO,NAME FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER_NO = "[123456]'

And for orders ending in a string:
SELECT ORDER_NO,NAME FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER_NO = "[123456'

[, ], [] are the Ends With, Starts With, Includes.
I believe those are faster than the LIKE lookups.

In addition, you could use LIKE with the ellipsis wildcard syntax:
SELECT ORDER_NO,NAME FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER_NO LIKE "...123456'
SELECT ORDER_NO,NAME FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER_NO LIKE "...123456...'
SELECT ORDER_NO,NAME FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER_NO LIKE "123456...'

Comment: Off topic, are you sure you made the right review choice here? :( https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13144329

Comment: No, not entirely sure.  I should probably have skipped the review instead of approving it.   The top changes were fine, but the code was harder to read.

Comment: This came up because the edit didn't make any changes (it just turned apostrophes into HTML entities, breaking the code). Definitely a skip or reject candidate